What does CsrfFilter do?
There is loading csrfToken from request with method this.tokenRepository.loadToken(request) and actualToken is also obtaining from request with method String actualToken = request.getHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName()). Then isn't csrfToken the same as actualToken?
what does the code snippet if (!csrfToken.getToken().equals(actualToken)) {} do?
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute(HttpServletResponse.class.getName(), response);

        CsrfToken csrfToken = this.tokenRepository.loadToken(request);
        final boolean missingToken = csrfToken == null;
        if (missingToken) {
            csrfToken = this.tokenRepository.generateToken(request);
            this.tokenRepository.saveToken(csrfToken, request, response);
        }
        request.setAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName(), csrfToken);
        request.setAttribute(csrfToken.getParameterName(), csrfToken);

        if (!this.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher.matches(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String actualToken = request.getHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName());
        if (actualToken == null) {
            actualToken = request.getParameter(csrfToken.getParameterName());
        }
        if (!csrfToken.getToken().equals(actualToken)) {
            if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("Invalid CSRF token found for "
                        + UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request));
            }
            if (missingToken) {
                this.accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response,
                        new MissingCsrfTokenException(actualToken));
            }
            else {
                this.accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response,
                        new InvalidCsrfTokenException(csrfToken, actualToken));
            }
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


The default implementation of CsrfTokenRepository is the HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository. So it will load csrf token from HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository instead of CookieCsrfTokenRepository.
